# Common Lisp implementation of Latent Semantic Indexing

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, latent-semantic-indexing

Is there a free Common Lisp implementation of Latent Semantic Indexing available? I would like to integrate that capability into an existing Lisp system.

Comment: Looking this up on the Wikipedia, I see I basically "reinvented" some aspect of this technique in the Meta-CVS program, whose `grab` command statistically analyzes the text files being imported and matches them against the baseline of the target branch, identifying files and symlinks that have been renamed or moved.  I built hash tables from tokenizing the files into pseudo-words, and performed some correlations: finding how much they have in common (while eliminating junk that many other files have in common). The matchings were ranked and the best ones chosen from the highest score on down.

Answer (score 2):

Latent Semantic Analysis is not my area of research, so I'm not familiar with these tools, and haven't used any of them, but a few things come up in a Google search that might be relevant.

- [cl-random-indexing](http://code.google.com/p/cl-random-indexing/) is tagged with LSA and LSI;
- [Lassie](http://www.ohloh.net/p/lassie), which at the time of writing had its most recent commit 6 years ago;